# Pass xml input to servlet

Tags: java, xml, servlets

I have a requirement is to call a Servlet, providing XML data as input.I have generated the XML data in my program and I have to pass this to my servlet.I am using `doPost()` method in my servlet.I don't have any idea about passing the XML data along with the servlet URL.

how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try not to think of it as `XML`. Treat it as a `String`, then parse it on the server side.

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" action="/myservlet">
    <input id="xml" type="hidden" value="XML DATA"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Click me"/>
</form>
```

Then in your `servlet`..

```
// Get the string from the post request.
String xmlContent = request.getParameter("xml");

// Create a document builder.
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource();

// Load the XML data into an InputSource object.
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlContent));

// Parse the raw data into a Document object.
Document doc = db.parse(is);
```